# Drop a part of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite stuck with a task I have to do.
I have a dataframe and I want to delete specific row of this drataframe according to some conditions.
when df[var1]>40 we note the value of df[var2] == x

I want to delete all the rows from the first row where df[var1]>40 included and df[var2] == x+1 excluded. Knowing that df[var2] will contain again this "x" value I want to keep. I just want to delete from df[var2] ==x to the first df[var2] == x+1

I am tearing my hairs finding some efficient code :(

I am using python.
Where its bold I want to delete

```
var2 : [1,1,**1,1**,2,2,2, etc ...1,1,1,2,2,etc...]
var1 : [4,12,**350,4**,18,12,etc....12,14,etc...]
```

I wrote this kind of code to explain what I want to do:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if df.var1[index]>40:
       x = df.var2[index]
    while df.var[index] == x :
       df.drop(row)
```

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df.head().to_string(index=False))`

Comment: difficult understand the question, if you can shown input data and the expected outcome, then it should be clear what needs to be done

Comment: Is it more clear now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
    var2  var1
0      1     4
1      1    12
2      1    55  # <- (1) remove from here
3      1    21
4      1    32  # <- (1) until then
5      2    23
6      2    29
7      2    49  # <- (2) remove from here
8      2    72
9      2    23  # <- (2) until then
10     1    12
11     1    49  # <- (3) remove from here
12     1    23  # <- (3) until then
```

Since you have cyclic values for `var2`, you can't use it directly, you have to create dummy groups. For each new group, find `var1` greater than 40 and apply cumulative sum. Only row where values equal 0 are kept.

```
>>> df[df.groupby(df['var2'].ne(df['var2'].shift()).cumsum())['var1']
         .apply(lambda x: x.gt(40).cumsum()).eq(0)]

    var2  var1
0      1     4
1      1    12
5      2    23
6      2    29
10     1    12
```

Comment: @Maxime. Can you check my answer if this solves your problem, please?

Comment: How did you become that’s good at Python ? I am a beginner and I long for improving my skills :) Do you have any tips ?

Comment: First, I use Python everyday. To increase your skills in Python, you can try to solve the problems of [Euler project](https://projecteuler.net/archives), a mixture of algorithm and programming. Next if you are interesting by Pandas and data process, I think StackOverflow is really good. I had a lot of trouble with Pandas at the beginning of the year and I tried to answer to questions. Now I'm pretty comfortable with this.

Comment: Important. Follow answers of users like [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael), [@BENY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/beny), 
[@Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston),
 [@Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely), [@Henry Ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker), [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway), why not [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien) and many other users, you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
df[df[var1] <= 40 | df[var2] != x+1]
```

Essentially, keeping the rows that have the reverse condition

Comment: Unfortunately not, because  x can take several values, depends where df[var1]>40 is in the dataframe...

Comment: Fine, how is x related to that position?

Comment: x is a sequential number from 1 to 50, like 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,,4,4,4,4,4 etc ... and it comes back to 1 again after 50. If in one row I observe  df[var]>40, I note that df[var2] == 4 for example, I want to delete all the rows from df[var]>40 to df[var2] == 5 excluded. But not all df[var2] ==4 in the dataframe just from df[var]>40 to df[var2] == x+1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax to extract data with multiple conditions by adding **"&"** between condition

```
df[(df[var1] <= 40) & (df[var2] != x+1)]
# df[(condition_1) & (condition_2) &...]
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, because x can take several values, depends where df[var1]>40 is in the dataframe...   x is a sequential number from 1 to 50, like 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,,4,4,4,4,4 etc ... and it comes back to 1 again after 50. If in one row I observe df[var]>40, I note that df[var2] == 4 for example, I want to delete all the rows from df[var]>40 to df[var2] == 5 excluded. But not all df[var2] ==4 in the dataframe just from df[var]>40 to df[var2] == x+1